# Ember Isotope infine scrolling

Tags: ember.js, jquery-isotope, infinite-scroll, masonry

I have an Ember.js app. I'm trying to apply Isotope masonry to a number of divs. This actually works, but because I'm using infinite scrolling (by getting the next n items from the backend, and updating the store), the new fetched items are not correctly appended.

Currently each items is displayed using a template with the {{#each}} tag. After a scroll event new items are appended. 
I however think using the following  [append from the Isotope docs](http://isotope.metafizzy.co/methods.html#appended) would solve my problem. But is it possible inserting the new items in this way with the following template using Ember?

This is my article.hbs:

```html
<div id="container" class="js-isotope">
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="articles">
      {{#each content itemController="article"}}
          <div class="item">
              ...
          </div>
      {{/each}}

</script>
</div>
```

Comment: I think #container needs to be within the script tag.

Comment: Answer to similar problem (using jQuery Masonry): [http://stackoverflow.com/a/27873683/4042635][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/a/27873683/4042635